# Problems Moving Method within NgOnInit Life Cycle Hook in Angular 2 App

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have some data that I'm populating to my Angular 2 app, and all is working as expected, EXCEPT, on occasion a page component loads before the information appears ready to display. On these occasions I can hit "refresh" and the data populates. However, this of course isn't the desired behavior. So my thought was to move the function responsible for calling this info into the ngOnInit lifecycle hook. However, my IDE shows an error when I try to do that, and I'm not sure why.

This is what relevant info of my current component looks like:

```
export class DoctorGeneralComponent extends EventHandler implements OnInit {

    @Input('doctor')
    public doctor: DoctorModel;

    constructor(private dialog: MdDialog) {
        super();
    }

    ngOnInit() {

     }

    public getPropertyStatus(name: string): string {
        return this.doctor ? this.doctor.getPropertyStatus(name) : '';
    }
}
```

If  I move this "gePropertyStatus" method into my ngOnInit, like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
   public getPropertyStatus(name: string): string {
    return this.doctor ? this.doctor.getPropertyStatus(name) : '';
}
```

... I get a ts "declaration or statement expected" error.

Any idea what's going on here, and how I can resolve it to include this method within my ngOnInit lifecycle hook?

Comment: You don't need to put getPropertyStatus method inside another method

Comment: In this case, yes you do if you have issues with the timing of data loading. That's the whole point of ngOnInit - it's there so that you can make sure certain methods are executed right when the component initiates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call it inside of ngOnInit, define it outside of it:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.getPropertyStatus("whatever name");
}

private getPropertyStatus(name: string): string {
  return this.doctor ? this.doctor.getPropertyStatus(name) : '';
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks. One note: I changed it slightly to this:
ngOnInit() { this.getPropertyStatus(name);